# data.table efficient alternative to grouped assignment as DT[ ,x:=f(y),by=z]?

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for the best alternative to the not yet implemented (to my knowledge) assignment by reference in a data.table by groups. Using the data.table example,

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
     x y v
[1,] a 1 1
[2,] a 3 2
[3,] a 6 3
[4,] b 1 4
[5,] b 3 5
[6,] b 6 6
[7,] c 1 7
[8,] c 3 8
[9,] c 6 9
```

I want to add a new column z, containing f(y,v) grouped by values of x (lets take f(y,v)=mean(y)+v). Note that I do not want to print or store the result of this computation as in

```
DT[,mean(y)+v,by=x]
      x        V1
 [1,] a  4.333333
 [2,] a  5.333333
 [3,] a  6.333333
 [4,] b  7.333333
 [5,] b  8.333333
 [6,] b  9.333333
 [7,] c 10.333333
 [8,] c 11.333333
 [9,] c 12.333333
```

but rather I want to add the result to DT:

```
     x y v        V1
[1,] a 1 1  4.333333
[2,] a 3 2  5.333333
[3,] a 6 3  6.333333
[4,] b 1 4  7.333333
[5,] b 3 5  8.333333
[6,] b 6 6  9.333333
[7,] c 1 7 10.333333
[8,] c 3 8 11.333333
[9,] c 6 9 12.333333
```

my data.table has 262 MB, such that

```
DT <- DT[,transform(.SD,mean(y)+v),by=x]
```

is not an option, since I cannot fit DT twice in memory (which is implied by the copy operation, I think). Fact is I've never seen that operation finish.

What alternatives do I have (until data.table comes with DT[,z:=mean(y)+v,by=x])?

I just read about DT[newDT]. What's wrong here?

```
newDT <- DT[,mean(y)+v,by=x]
      x        V1
 [1,] a  4.333333
 [2,] a  5.333333
 [3,] a  6.333333
 [4,] b  7.333333
 [5,] b  8.333333
 [6,] b  9.333333
 [7,] c 10.333333
 [8,] c 11.333333
 [9,] c 12.333333
```

(which is doable memory wise.) then:

```
> DT[newDT]
setkey(DT,x)
setkey(newDT,x)
x y v        V1
a 1 1  4.333333
a 3 2  4.333333
a 6 3  4.333333
a 1 1  5.333333
a 3 2  5.333333
a 6 3  5.333333
a 1 1  6.333333
a 3 2  6.333333
a 6 3  6.333333
b 1 4  7.333333
b 3 5  7.333333
b 6 6  7.333333
b 1 4  8.333333
b 3 5  8.333333
b 6 6  8.333333
b 1 4  9.333333
b 3 5  9.333333
b 6 6  9.333333
c 1 7 10.333333
c 3 8 10.333333
c 6 9 10.333333
c 1 7 11.333333
c 3 8 11.333333
c 6 9 11.333333
c 1 7 12.333333
c 3 8 12.333333
c 6 9 12.333333
```

but that's not what I want. What's the mistake here?

Answer (score 4):

```
DT[, xm := ave(y, x, FUN=mean) + v]
```

Comment: +1 very nice solution, I only wrote my lengthy one because I thought yours doesn't work. Having a second look on `ave`, I think you just meant `DT[, xm := ave(y, x, FUN=mean) + v]`. Then it works like a charm and could be the most efficient.

Comment: +1 Since `,by` is faster than `ave`, though, this should be more efficient (although ugly) until "`:=` by group" is finished: `DT[,xm:=DT[,mean(y)+v,by=x][[2]]]`

Comment: thanks a ton guys. I didn't even know `ave` existed. looking forward to the `:=` by group!

Comment: I think of `table`, `tapply` and `ave` as my summarization workhorses. Sometimes `aggregate` is needed but I mess up with it too often to feel entirely comfortable with it. I wish those three had a more consistent syntax, but mostly whine to myself.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

```
DT[, list(fvy = mean(y)), by="x"][DT][, fvy := fvy + v]
```

So basically, I split it up into two parts: First, I compute the mean of `y` and add that to DT, then I add `v` to the mean of `y`. Memory-wise I'm not sure if this really helps, but there is a good chance the author will have a look and let us know ;-)

Regarding your question why it's not working: Basically, you end up with two data.tables that you want to merge: `DT` and `newDT`. Both data.tables have every key three times. So obviously, when you merge them, every combination is in the results and that's why you get a data.table with 9 a, b, and c's.

So to do it your way which is quite similar to mine you need a second key:

```
newDT <- DT[,list(fvy=mean(y)+v, v),by=x]
setkey(newDT, x, v)
setkey(DT, x, v)
DT[newDT]
      x v y       fvy
 [1,] a 1 1  4.333333
 [2,] a 2 3  5.333333
 [3,] a 3 6  6.333333
 [4,] b 4 1  7.333333
 [5,] b 5 3  8.333333
 [6,] b 6 6  9.333333
 [7,] c 7 1 10.333333
 [8,] c 8 3 11.333333
 [9,] c 9 6 12.333333
```

Comment: +1 for effort. We really just need `:=` by group, don't we. Nearly there. Btw, compound `:=` comes in handy sometimes: `DT[,newx:=colA+2][,newy:=newx*2][,newz:=colA+newx+newy]...`

Comment: But I won't be doing multiple `:=` by `by` yet, just in case anyone is hoping for that. It'll just be one `:=` by `by` for the next version.  Future versions might be `DT[,{newx:=colB+2;newy:=newx+colC},by=colA]`